# Magento 2: Get Parent Category ID of Category ID

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-1.9

How does one get the parent category ID of a category ID in Magento 2?

In Magento 1, I did it with the following:

```
$product_id = 101; //for example
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id); //get product object by product ID
$category_ids = $product->getCategoryIds(); //array of all categories that the product is in
foreach ($category_ids as $cat_ids) {
    $parent_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id)->getParentId(); //
    echo $parent_id; //outputs an int ID of parent category
}
```

In Magento 2, I've been attempting the same with the following:

```
$product_id = 101; //again, for example
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productRepository = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
$product = $productRepository->getById($product_id); //get product object by product ID
$category_ids = $product->getCategoryIds(); //array of all categories that the product is in
foreach ($category_ids as $cat_ids) {
    echo $cat_ids;
}
```

Up to here, my code is working perfectly and the $category_ids is an array of all the categories that the product is in. However I cannot figure out how to get the parent category IDs of each child category ID in the $category_ids array.

NOTICE* I'm aware that I'm not officially supposed to directly used the ObjectManager, so please save this from your answer. I am seeking to specifically use the ObjectManager in this manner to iterate over $category_ids and load the parent category IDs for each child category ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like so often, there are multiple ways to achieve this.

### The CategoryFactory route

To load a category directly, you load it via the Factory Singleton responsible for the `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category` class. This is the `\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory` class. From each instance of `Category`, you can simple call the method `getParentId()` to get the parent ID.

```
foreach ($categoryIds as $categoryId) {
    try {
        $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        /* Handle this appropriately... */
    }
    echo 'Parent Category ID: ', $category->getParentId(), PHP_EOL;
}
```

In this example, `$categoryIds` is the `array` of Category IDs you extracted from your `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` instance.

### The CategoryRepository route

Or preferably you can use a Singleton instance of the `\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository` class as a wrapper around the `Factory`. It will handle all the loading with some added error handling and it will also store a reference to the loaded category for later reuse. So if you are doing this multiple times during one execution, or suspect that you will load the same category later on, using the `Repository` will optimize your performance.

```
foreach ($categoryIds as $categoryId) {
    try {
        $category = $this->_categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        /* Handle this appropriately... */
    }
    echo 'Parent Category ID: ', $category->getParentId(), PHP_EOL;
}
```

### The Collection route

This should be a much faster route, as you (1) load all categories once from database instead of using several multiple sql calls in the backend and (2) you have some control over what is populated in the `Category`, and what is left out. Please be aware, that pretty much only what you put in `addAttributeToSelect()` will be populated in the Collection. But if you're only after the `parent_id` this should not be an issue.

First, make sure you are [familiar with collections](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-crud-model-magento-2.html), then acquire a *CollectionFactory* Singleton for `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory` and then populate it like so:

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category */
$collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();

# Specifically select the parent_id attribute
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('parent_id');

# Only select categories with certain entity_ids (category ids)
$collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $categoryIds])

# Iterate over results and print them out!
foreach ($collection as $category) {
    echo 'Parent Category ID: ', $category->getParentId(), PHP_EOL;
}
```

With great powers comes great risk, however. This above code will have no error correction whatsoever. If there is a logical database error, such as a product which points to a missing category, this category will just be omitted from the collection and it will be up to you as a programmer to spot that and deal with it. Also, you will have to decide for yourself on how you are handling store view and active/inactive categories via filters to the collection.

### The Direct Database route

Ok, I would not recommend this route unless you know **exactly** what you are doing, and are in desperate need for performance.

This will be crazy-fast, but there are all sorts of problems, like relying on the underlying data storage and data structure, not to mention that you are open to (very unlikely, to be fair) future updates to the underlying database structure, either directly via Magento upgrades or via (nasty) 3rd party modules. Not the mention the dangers of SQL injections or XSS attacks. (*Though, you should always keep this in mind, with all 4 methods.*)

As you are using the ObjectManager directly, I assume you won't mind these drawbacks, however, so I though I'd give you this option as well.

The basic pseudo-sql is:

```
select parent_id from <name of catalog_category_entity table> where entity_id in (<sanitized, comma-separated list of category ids);
```

First, acquire an instance of the `\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection` class. You will use this to get the necessary table name for `catalog_category_entity`, as well as getting the database connection. Then you should sanitize your data and finally, the bind and execute the query and fetch your data.

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Connection */
$connection = $this->_resourceConnection->getConnection();

# Get prefixed table name of catalog_category_entity
$categoryEntityTableName = $this->_resourceConnection->getTableName('catalog_category_entity');

# Sanitize the $categoryIds array using a bit of overkill
array_walk_recursive($categoryIds, function(&$value, $key){
    $value = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
});

# Prepare a sql statement which fetches entity_id and parent_id
$preparedStatement = $this->connection->prepare('select entity_id, parent_id from ' . $categoryEntityTableName . ' where entity_id in (' . implode(',', array_fill(0, sizeof($categoryIds), '?')) . ')');

# Bind sanitized $categoryIds array to statement and execute said statement in one single step 
$preparedStatement->execute($categoryIds);

# fetch result as a key-value pair array of entity_id=>parent_id
$parentIds = $preparedStatement->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);

# Iterate over results and print them out!
foreach ($parentIds as $categoryId => $parentId) {
    echo 'Parent Category ID: ', (int)$parentId, PHP_EOL;
}
```

### Footnote

I assume you are well aware of the pros and cons of using the `ObjectManager` directly, so I'll spare you the lecture ;-). However, for future reference I'll also have to state to future readers stumbling upon this answer that if they are unaware on how to acquire instances of the `CategoryFactory`, `CategoryRepository`, `CollectionFactory` or `ResourceConnection` classes, I highly recommend them to do so via the intended [Dependency Injection](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html) mechanism.

Comment: Aron, sorry for the late response. This answer was so comprehensive, I need to express great gratitude! It definitely expanded my understanding of Magento. I am still a beginner, so some of your answer took additional research on my part to understand. Here is my working code:

Comment: ```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productRepository = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
$product = $productRepository->getById($product_id);
$categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();

foreach($categoryIds as $catid) {
    $category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($catid);
    $parent_id = $category->getParentId();
}
```